# Creating a cluetip title

Tags: javascript, jquery, cluetip

I have a cluetip that is displayed when a user clicks a link.  When the tip is displayed I want it to have a title but it does not want to show the title.

```
$('#spouseMortalityImage').cluetip({ 
    titleAttribute: 'alt',
    titleAttribute: 'Title',
    sticky: 'true',
    closeText: '<img align="right" width="16px" height="16px" src="../images/buttonTip.gif" alt="close" />',
    closePosition: 'title', 
    ajaxSettings:{
        data:{
            age:"<%= personalInfoBean.getSpouseAge()%>",
            gender:"<%= personalInfoBean.getSpouseGender()%>",
            country:$("input[name=planningCountry]").val(),
        }
    }
});
```

I want the title to be displayed but its not showing up.  This is the HTML im using.

```
<td class="centerAlignedContext" width="50%">
    <pp:text name="personalInfoBean" property="clientMortality" size="8" maxlength="3" style="text-align:center;" styleClass="wamoney" />
</td>
<td width="20%">  
    <a class="title" href="#" title="Chance of Survival"></a>
    <img id="clientMortalityImage" style="height:15px;" src="../images/suggestion.jpg" rel="ProbabilityOfSurvival.do"/>
</td>
```

Comment: What's your html look like? You also have two `titleAttribute` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used this plugin but going through the documentation, I wanted to suggest some changes which may work.
In your JQuery code, make these changes and try it:

- Remove all `titleAttribute` options.
- Add instead a `title` attribute like `<img id="spouseMortalityImage" title="Hello"/>` in your markup to the correct  tag with id `spouseMortalityImage` which you have shown in Jquery. In the markup you have posted currently, I do not see this element. Instead I see an `<img>` tag with ID `clientMortalityImage`

Comment: When I change the closePosition to 'top' my button does not show up, and the showTitle is true.

Comment: Your JQuery seems to be putting the clue tip on the element with ID `spouseMortalityImage` which I guess is just another image like `clientMortalityImage` which you have posted in your markup.
 Can you change the `closePosition` back to `'title'` and remove the `titleAttribute` option in your Jquery completely. Instead add a `title` attribute like `title="Hello"` in your `<img>` tag where you want to display the cluetip on hover.

Comment: Let me kow if this works. Sorry that the earlier suggestion did not work. As I said I am not familiar with this plugin.

Comment: Thats Great! I have edited my answer to include what I wrote in the comment. Please Mark the answer as correct, so that people having similar issue will get the solution.